# Why does GCC allow use of round() in C++ even with the ansi and pedantic flags?

Tags: c++, gcc, rounding, c++98

Is there a good reason why this program compiles under GCC even with the `-ansi` and `-pedantic` flags?

```
#include <cmath>

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
     double x = 0.5;

     return static_cast<int>(round(x));
}
```

This compiles clean (no warnings, even) with `g++ -ansi -pedantic -Wall test.cpp -o test`.

I see two problems:

1. `round()` shouldn't be available to C++ in ISO-conformant mode (since it comes from C99)
2. Even if `round()` were available in this case, it should only be so from the `std` namespace

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2002-09/msg00580.html). It's been around for a surprisingly long while. Apparently, there has not been enough of a collective desire to fix it. With a new version of C++ just around the corner which will adopt the C99 functions from math.h, it seems unlikely it will ever be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I might be off base here but doesn't gcc's -ansi flag apply to the code constructs (ie, disable GCC *language* extensions) rather than switching all libraries into strict ANSI compliant mode as well?

Comment: the man page to gcc states that some function will not be defined when the ansi flag is set, but not that only ansi functions will be defined

Comment: @josefx: See my comments to D. Shawley. After investigating more, I've learned that library extensions cannot "alter the behavior of well-formed programs". So it seems to me that adding a `round()` extension to the library would be illegal, which makes the behavior of the `-ansi` flag moot.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the Standards specify what symbols are required to be defined and in which header they are defined.  I do not believe that the Standards state that no other symbols may be defined.  More to the point, `std::round()` will not be defined by a free symbol called `round()` can be defined.

Comment: Okay, that may be true but the purpose of `-ansi`, according to the GCC manual, is to *disable* all non-standard extensions. Any such additional library functions would be extensions of the standard (whether such extensions are allowed by the standard is tangential to this question).

Comment: I should amend my previous comment: `-ansi` disables *conflicting* extensions, while `-pedantic` is supposed to disable all extensions.

Comment: Actually, I've looked at both C and C++ standards and although they allow additional library functions, such extensions cannot "alter the behavior of any well-formed program". This implies that they cannot reserve any additional identifiers (i.e. a well-formed program that defines its own round() function would break by the library extending the standard with its own round function). Any additional library functions must have names that are *already* reserved, such as `_Round()`.