# 'round' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, g++

I'm try to compile this code:

```
#include <cmath>
double gravity (double level) {
    return 0.02 * std::round(level);
}
```

But GCC is telling me:

```
error: 'round' is not a member of 'std'
```

I know I've used the `round` function many times in **ISO C++98** before. Unusually, `round` and `::round` both work.

What gives?

*Update*: I was compiling with `g++ -std=c++98 -Wall -pedantic`.
Switching to `std=c++0x` works.

But why do the unqualified/anonymous `round` and `::round` both work if `std::round` doesn't?

Comment: no, it's not: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c

Comment: @HugoCorrá yes it is, but only in C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Comment: @juanchopanza iteresting, I didn't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) functions are C++11, so you would need to compile with C++11 or a more recent standard enabled.

Answer (score 15):

I've done a bit of research, here's what I've found:

`round` is defined in **ISO C++11**, as it contains the **ISO C99** standard library.

`round` is not part of the **ISO C++98**, which uses the **ISO C90** standard library.

That's why it's not in namespace `std` for **C++98**.

But `g++` is (incorrectly) including the **C99** headers, even when compiled with `-std=c++98 -pedantic`, which should disable all non-standard stuff:

> GNU_SOURCE is defined by G++ and ... it implies _USE_ISOC99

(from http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2002-09/msg00580.html)

This is why `::round` works.

This apparently is a bug in GCC: [Why does GCC allow use of round() in C++ even with the ansi and pedantic flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882689/why-does-gcc-allow-use-of-round-in-c-even-with-the-ansi-and-pedantic-flags)

Other C++ compilers may not provide a `round` function (since it's not required by the standard), so I should define my own.

Comment: You should not try and define your own round, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24348037/1708801) it is actually a lot harder than it looks. Sadly tons of answers to similar threads do exactly that and they mostly wrong is subtle ways. Some get downvoted but many are even accepted answers.

Comment: This hilarious. My workaround for lack of `std::round` in C++03 is to use `round` from `<math.h>` instead and rely on a GCC bug that _accidentally provides the function_. Somehow this bug isn't even inherited by `<cmath>`. Good job, C++!

Comment: @PreferenceBean I've since migrated to C++11: `gcc -std=c++11`. It has a `std::round` function, among other things.

Comment: @QuasarDonkey: That's nice. I am on C++03.

Answer (score 6):

how about

```
float myRoundFunc(float toRound)
{
  return std::ceil(toRound - 0.5);
}
```

That way there is no comparison and it will round properly.

Comment: `std::ceil(toRound - 0.5f);` Just use the 'f' suffix, such that the type is matching.

Answer (score 5):

old topic but maybe usefull for the ones searching in google:

```
//TODO: C++11 got round() function defined in math.h
float distance = sqrt((float)(plus_x * plus_x + plus_y * plus_y));
if (distance >= floor(distance)+0.5) distance = ceil(distance);
else distance = floor(distance);
```

Answer (score 4):

In the C++03 standard, the normative reference for the *standard C library* is ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (C90), which *does not* include the `round` function. In C++11, it is ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99), which *does* include the `round` function.

The contents of `<cmath>` in each C++ standard are the same as `math.h` from the corresponding standard C library except for a few changes (§26.8/4 in C++11):

> The contents of these headers [`<cmath>` and `<cstdlib>`] are the same as the Standard C library headers `<math.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` respectively [...]

They are, however, in namespace scope of `std` (§17.6.1.2/4 in C++11):

> In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace std.

So, to wrap it up, the `round` function is not available in C++03, so compile with the `-std=c++0x` option and refer to it as `std::round`.

Comment: Thanks, but if the cmath and math.h are the same, it doesn't explain why ::round works but std::round doesn't. I'm compiling with g++ -std=c++98 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic.

Comment: I gave it a test and you're right. I can only imagine that `<cmath>` does `#include <math.h>` and the pulls in only the C90 versions of the functions to `std`, leaving everything else still around in the global namespace. Functions that should be available in `std`, such as `sin`, do indeed work like `std::sin(90.0)`.